# React Native create new objects whenever Array increases in size

Tags: react-native

I am creating function that is supposed to fetch POST to my API with new recipes. I am using React Native and Nodejs + MongoDB as my backend. I was able to display successfully everything but ability for use to add new ingredients for the recipe. As you can see i tried doing it by adding a button that increases the index and then creating new inputs for Array(index). However despite my best efforts it doesn't work and I am getting these errors instead:

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

and

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`.
```

if anyone has any idea why is this happening or how can I do this differently I would be utterly grateful because I spent an entire day trying to get this working.

Here is my component code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, TextInput, Text, ScrollView, View } from "react-native";
import Styles from "../../styles/Styles";
import Alert from "../elements/Alert";
import APIRequest from "../elements/APIRequest";

export default function CreateNewRecipe(props) {
  const [dishName, setdishName] = useState("");
  const [category, setcategory] = useState("");
  const [author, setauthor] = useState("");
  const [ingredients, setingredients] = useState([]);
  const [cookingTime, setcookingTime] = useState("");
  const [sourceUrl, setsourceUrl] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setimageUrl] = useState("");
  const [isPublished, setisPublished] = useState("true");
  const [price, setprice] = useState("");
  const [tags, settags] = useState([]);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  async function create() {
    let item = {
      dishName,
      category,
      author,
      ingredients,
      cookingTime,
      sourceUrl,
      imageUrl,
      isPublished,
      price,
      tags,
    };


    const result = await APIRequest(
      "http://x.x.x.x:1234/api/courses",
      "POST",
      JSON.stringify(item)
    );

    if (result.status !== 200) {
      return setAlert(result.status + " " + result.statusText);
    }
  }

  const handleIngredientsChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log(event);
    const shallowCopy = [...ingredients];
    shallowCopy[index] = {
      ...shallowCopy[index],
      [event.target.id]: event,
    };

    setingredients(shallowCopy);
  };

  function createIngredient(index) {
    return (
      <View>
        <View key={"key" + index}>
          <View style={Styles.text}>
            <Text>Quantity</Text>
          </View>

          <TextInput
            key={"quantity"}
            style={
              (Styles.formControl,
              {
                marginLeft: 1,
                marginRight: 1,
                width: 5,
              })
            }
            onChange={event => handleIngredientsChange(event, index)}
          />
          <View style={(Styles.text, { marginRight: 1 })}> Unit </View>
          <View>
            <TextInput
              key={"unit"}
              style={(Styles.formControl, { width: 5 })}
              onChange={event => handleIngredientsChange(event, index)}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={(Styles.text, { marginLeft: 1 })}> Description </View>

          <TextInput
            key={"description"}
            style={(Styles.formControl, { marginLeft: 1 })}
            onChange={event => handleIngredientsChange(event, index)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView style={(Styles.updateBody, { minWidth: 70 })}>
      <View style={Styles.updateModal}>
        <View
          style={(Styles.bigBar, { textAlign: "center", marginBottom: 10 })}
        >
          <Text style={Styles.h1}>Create {"\n"} new recipe</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#f1f1f1",
            padding: 3,
            borderRadius: 1,
            marginBottom: 7,
          }}
        >
          <View style={{}}>
            {alert !== "" && (
              <View style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Alert alert={alert}></Alert>
              </View>
            )}
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Name of the course</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                style={Styles.formControl}
                value={dishName}
                onChange={e => setdishName(e)}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Category</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                style={Styles.text}
                value={category}
                onChange={e => setcategory(e)}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Author</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => setauthor(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                value={author}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.text} style={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
              <Text>Ingredients</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.smlBtn}>
              <Button
                onPress={() => setIndex(index + 1)}
                title="Add product"
                color="#40b48e"
              />
            </View>
            {[...Array(index)].map((_, index) => createIngredient(index))}
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Cooking time</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => setcookingTime(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                value={cookingTime}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Source url</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => setsourceUrl(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                value={sourceUrl}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Image url</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => setimageUrl(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                value={imageUrl}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Publish state</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => setisPublished(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                placeholder={"default: true"}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Price</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => setprice(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                value={price}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={Styles.text}>
                <Text>Tags</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                onChange={e => settags(e)}
                style={Styles.text}
                value={tags}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <Button onPress={create} title="Submit" />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Here is an example of my data:

```
{
        "isPublished": true,
        "tags": [
            "pizza", "greek"
        ],
        "dishName": "Greek pizza",
        "author": "Paolo",
        "category": "pizza",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": 0.75,
                "unit": "cup",
                "description": "warm water"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 0.5,
                "unit": "cup",
                "description": "bread flour"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1.5,
                "unit": "tea spoon",
                "description": "sea salt"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "unit": "cup",
                "description": "baby arugula"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 0.67,
                "unit": "cup",
                "description": "grape tomatoes halved"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "unit": "drizzle",
                "description": "olive oil"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1.5,
                "unit": "tea spoon",
                "description": "dry active yeast"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 2,
                "unit": "tea spoon",
                "description": "sugar"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "unit": "lb",
                "description": "hummus any variety"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 0.67,
                "unit": "cup",
                "description": "good pitted greek olives"
            },
        {
                "quantity": 0.25,
                "unit": "cup",
                "description": "crumbled feta cheese"
            }
        ],
        "cookingTime": 75,
        "sourceUrl": "https://www.crete.pl/kuchnia-grecka-dania-glowne-wegetarianskie/grecka-pizza-z-feta.html",
        "imageUrl": "https://www.crete.pl/zdjecia/grecka-pizza-z-feta/pizza1.jpg",
        "price": 35.99
    }
```

Comment: Is there noone that could help? I am still trying to figure this out but I am not doing much progress :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, what I needed to do is to change code like this:

```
{ingredients.map(({ quantity, unit, description }, index) => {
                // console.log(quantity, unit, description);
                return (
                  <View style={Styles.ing} key={"key" + index}>
                    <Text style={Styles.text}>Quantity </Text>
                    <View>
                      <Input
                        key={"quantity" + index}
                        style={
                          (Styles.formControl,
                          {
                            marginLeft: 1,
                            marginRight: 1,
                            width: "100%",
                          })
                        }
                        onChangeText={event =>
                          handleIngredientsChange(event, index)
                        }
                        value={quantity.toString()}
                      />
                    </View>

                    <View style={{ marginRight: 2 }}>
                      <Text style={Styles.text}>Unit </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Input
                        key={"unit" + index}
                        style={
                          (Styles.formControl,
                          {
                            marginLeft: 1,
                            marginRight: 1,
                            width: "100%",
                          })
                        }
                        onChangeText={event =>
                          handleIngredientsChange(event, index)
                        }
                        value={unit}
                      />
                    </View>

                    <View style={{ marginLeft: 1 }}>
                      <Text style={Styles.text}>Description </Text>
                    </View>
                    <Input
                      key={"description" + index}
                      style={
                        (Styles.formControl,
                        {
                          marginLeft: 1,
                          marginRight: 1,
                          width: "100%",
                        })
                      }
                      onChangeText={event =>
                        handleIngredientsChange(event, index)
                      }
                      value={description}
                    />
                  </View>
                );
              })}
```